# Exception KeyError if call focus_get() when down arrow clicked on widget Combo

Tags: python, tkinter

Try to view where the focus by following code, but get Exception `KeyError` if call `focus_get()` when down arrow clicked on widget Combo.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def show_focus():
    label.configure(text=f'Focus at {root.focus_get()}')
    root.after(100, show_focus)

font = ('Courier New', 16)
root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root, text='Focus at', width=40, font=font, anchor='w')
label.pack(anchor='w', fill='x')

value1 = tk.StringVar()
value1.set("Entry")
entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=value1, width=40, font=font, bg='green', fg='black')
entry.pack(anchor='w', fill='x')

value2 = tk.StringVar()
value2.set("Male")
combo = ttk.Combobox(root, values=['Male', 'Female'], textvariable=value2, width=40, height=5, font=font)
combo.pack(anchor='w')

show_focus()

root.mainloop()
```

```py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Software\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Software\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 814, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "D:\tkinter focus_get.py", line 5, in show_focus
    label.configure(text=f'Focus at {root.focus_get()}')
  File "C:\Software\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 758, in focus_get
    return self._nametowidget(name)
  File "C:\Software\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1507, in nametowidget
    w = w.children[n]
KeyError: 'popdown'
```

In method `focus_get()` of tkinter

```py
...
name = self.tk.call('focus')    #name: <string object: '.!combobox.popdown.f.l'>
...
self._nametowidget(name)
...

def nametowidget(self, name):
        """Return the Tkinter instance of a widget identified by
        its Tcl name NAME."""
        name = str(name).split('.')
        w = self

        if not name[0]:
            w = w._root()
            name = name[1:]

        for n in name:
            if not n:
                break
            w = w.children[n]   # '!combobox' in root.children, but 'popdown' not in combo.children, so it get KeyError here.

        return w

_nametowidget = nametowidget
```

My question is how can I get where the focus, but to avoid situation like this one. Maybe `try except` statement can skip exception, but it will get wrong focus at that moment.

[Update]

```py
def show_focus():
    try:
        label.configure(text=f'Focus at {root.focus_get()}')
    except:
        # root.after(100, show_focus), if this statement put here, this function will stop if no exception
        pass
    root.after(100, show_focus)    # statement here to keep update where the focus
```

Comment: Probably because the 'dropdown button' is not something valid, with `nametowidget()`. About `try`/`except`: Put `root.after(...)` inside `except` too.

Comment: `Put root.after(...) inside except too. `, it will stop to update where the focus when exception. It looks like there's a bug when some conditions for method `focus_get`.

Comment: No it wont. As long as you click somewhere else other than pop-down button

Comment: update in post.

Comment: What is wrong with the updated code. It shows correct focus to me.

Comment: Exception and no exception run same statement, just put one statement after try/except, should be the same.

Comment: Click on down arrow and do nothing after you clicked on entry, it will show you on entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get over the error by ignoring each press on the 'popdown' button.

```
def show_focus():
    if str(root.tk.call(combo,'state')) != 'pressed':
        label.configure(text=f'Focus at {root.focus_get()}')
    else:
        label.configure(text=f'Focus at {str(combo)}')
    root.after(100, show_focus)
```

This is a way around the issue as 'popdown' button is not identified by `nametowidget()`(which is used to return the widget name when using `focus_get()`). I was able to find a similar bug at https://bugs.python.org/issue18686